# How to add WPA Enterprise TLS connection in Kubuntu?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet, network-manager, kde

how to add WPA2 Enterprise connection over TLS in Kubuntu 10.13, using its standard network manager? I want to connect to my university’s eduroam network and cannot do it.

When I try to do it in connections editor, when I do “add wireless connection”, after filling all necessary data (network’s ssid and security details with WPA2 Enterprise over TLS authentication) after clicking “OK” nothing happens. No connection’s being added.

When I add some empty connection (only ssid filled, no security checked) it is being added to connections list, and I can edit it, but again after inserting security data it does not save changes. So I cannot configure this connection.

Details I try to insert:

```
Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: TLS
Identity: my.identity@student.put.poznan.pl
User’s certificate: [None]
CA certificate: [path/to/cacert.pem]
User’s private key: [path/to/user.p12]
User’s key password: [pass]
```

What are other ways to set the connection?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new connection to eduroam without setting security options (just to get connection file with UUID etc.)
2. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<connection_name_from_point_one>` as root
3. Delete everything but connection, ipv4, and ipv6 sections
4. Add:

   ```
   [802-11-wireless]
   ssid=eduroam
   mode=infrastructure
   security=802-11-wireless-security

   [802-11-wireless-security]
   key-mgmt=wpa-eap

   [802-1x]
   eap=tls
   identity=XXXXXXXX@student.put.poznan.pl
   client-cert=file:///path/to/your/private/key/XXXXXXXX@student.put.poznan.pl.p12
   ca-cert=file:///path/to/ca-cert/cacert.pem
   private-key=file:///path/to/your/private/key/XXXXXXXX@student.put.poznan.pl.p12
   private-key-password=XXXXXXXX
   system-ca-certs=false
   ```

   I think `client-cert` can be any file. The network doesn't need this, but NetworkManager does.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently if you skip the user certificate, Network Manager won't save the configuration. Try to use the same certificate for both CA certificate and User certificate.

Comment: This will not work - user certificate is specific to each user, CA is a different cert.